# Prove that a logic can not distinguish two models

Tags: logic, model-theory

In order to prove unequal expressivity between two logics $L_1$ and $L_2$, one may provide two models which $L_1$ can distinguish, i.e. $L_1$ has a formula $\phi$ which is true in the one but false in the other, but $L_2$ can not distinguish those models. How shall you prove that $L_2$ can not distinguish those models ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*EDIT: a source you might be interested in, with information about tons of different logics, is the collection ["Model-theoretic logics"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235417263).*

Well, it depends on what $L_2$ is - different logics have different properties, and there's no "one-size-fits-all" technique.

The standard example, just because it's so well understood, is when $L_2$ is [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic). Here we have lots of tools:

- [Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game) can be used to show that two structures are elementarily (= first-order) equivalent; for instance, $(\mathbb{Z},<)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z},<)$.
- First-order theories are preserved under [ultrapowers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct): if one structure is an ultrapower of the other, they will be elementarily equivalent.
- It's often easy to find the quantifier-free (resp. existential) theories of the two structures involved and show that they are equal; if we can then prove the appropriate [quantifier-elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_elimination) (resp. [model-completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_complete_theory)), this shows that the two structures are elementarily equivalent.
- And so forth.

Other logics, as I said above, require different techniques. E.g.:

- For appropriate fragments of infinitary logic $L_{\omega_1\omega}$, we have the [Barwise compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barwise_compactness_theorem).
- For the class-sized infinitary logic $L_{\infty\omega}$, we have [back-and-forth systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method) (due to Karp), or equivalently the property of being isomorphic in some [forcing extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)) (due to Barwise).
- And there are times when there is no easy tool available, and we have to argue "sentence-by-sentence" - e.g. by induction on complexity. This is often the case when working with set-theoretically "badly behaved" logics like [second-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic), and equivalence with respect to such logics can be [extremely complicated to deal with](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161676/the-non-absoluteness-of-second-order-elementary-equivalence).

---

Another important point is that we don't always need to make the two structures precise. For example, suppose we make a new logic $L_W$ by augmenting first-order logic with a **well-foundedness quantifier**, $\mathbb{W}$ *(I really want this to be an upside-down "W," in keeping with "$\forall$" and "$\exists$," but don't know how - if you can get this to happen, feel free to edit and then delete this parenthetical)*, which behaves as follows: for a formula $\varphi(x, y, \overline{z})$ and with free variables $x, y,$ and possibly others $\overline{z}$, we interpret "$\mathbb{W}x, y(\varphi(x, y,\overline{z}))$" as saying "there is no infinite sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, ...$ satisfying $\varphi(a_i, a_{i+1},\overline{z})$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$."

This logic pins down the structure "$\mathcal{N}=(\mathbb{N}, <)$" up to isomorphism: take the usual first-order theory of $\mathcal{N}$ and add the sentence "$\mathbb{W}x, y(y<x)$." But first-order logic does *not* pin down $\mathcal{N}$ up to isomorphism, by the compactness theorem! This means that there must be a structure first-order equivalent to $\mathcal{N}$, but not $L_W$-equivalent; *and we don't need to know exactly what it is*. A lot of the time we can in fact build explicit examples (e.g. $(\mathbb{N}\oplus\mathbb{Z},<)$), but (a) not needing to can save us time, and (b) sometimes we can't (although I'm not aware of any important case where we *really* can't give *some* description of the culprit).

Comment: Those are good starting points for me. The two logics I'm particularly concerned about are two modal logics where $L_2$ is an extension of $L_1$.